# HTML/CSS Cropping Image from left AND right when screen becomes too small

Tags: html, css

first of all... I am totally new so i apologize if i forgot some important stuff that helps you to answer my Question. I´ll give my best.

This is my Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
    <figure>
        <div>
            <img src="a.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="b.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="c.jpg">
        </div>
    </figure>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {

.slider figure div{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

.slider figure img{
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;    
}


.slider figure {
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation-name: slidy;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 15s;
}


@keyframes slidy{

    0%{
        left: 0%;
    }

    31%{
        left: 0%;
    }
    35%{
        left: -100%;
    }
    66%{
        left: -100%;
    }
    70%{
        left: -200%;
    }
    95%{
        left: -200%;
    }
    100%{
        left: 0;
    }
}
}
```

The CSS Slider Code works just the way i want for "normal" Screen sizes like the iPad-Pro and PC-Screen. 
Obviously when the Screen gets too small (a Phone for example) the Images are going to look ugly because i resize them with the Browser Window.

So when the Screen gets too small i want to cut the Image on the left AND right side (NOT resizing with the Browser Window) so one is able to see the center of the Image and not a warped picture.

I tried solving my Problem with transform but i couldn't get it done because everything i tried ruined the slider.
Do you guys have any other idea?

Comment: as you are using slider, must be a jquery plugin, read its doc, generally these have option to how to show image in diff screens

Comment: @RakeshSoni "...must be a jquery plugin..." - I don't see anything in this post related to jQuery. It looks like OP is rolling his/her own slider. Is that true, OP?

Comment: @J.Titus my bad :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

If anybody has the same Problem i had... here´s my solution. 
I used background pictures. So i was able to use

```
@media
```

for different screen sizes (i just used the same picture with different sizes) and

```
background-position:center;
```

so the image gets cropped from the left and right side.
Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
.slider figure img{

 min-width: 50px !important;

}

.slider figure {

text-align:center  !important; 
over-flow:hidden  !important;    

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Subi I added those lines into my Code but unfortunately that didn't work for me. Maybe i misunderstood your idea to solve my problem.

Comment: @Subi You don't have to be sorry ;) I appreciate your idea!

Answer (score 0):

In that media query you are setting the width of the image to be 100%; So it will be resized with browser window. You can remove that and also center the image by adding text-align: center; to the parent. However once the browser window becomes smaller than the img there will be an overflow scroll.

```
.slider figure div{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.slider figure img{

}
```

If you want this overflow image to be centered at all times, that would involve some javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried that but unfortunately it doesn't help either.